# The Output of the code is not coming as expected

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, hashmap, heapsort

I am trying to sort the objects of the class hashtable using heapsort

```
struct hashmap{
        int key;
        int value;   };


vector<hashmap> heap;
int n;
void heapify(int i)
{
    int l,r,max=i;
    l=2*i+1;
    r=2*i+2;
    if((heap[r].key>heap[max].key)||((heap[r].key=heap[max].key)&&(heap[r].value>heap[max].value)))
    {
       max=r;
    }
    else if((heap[l].key>heap[max].key)||((heap[l].key=heap[max].key)&&(heap[l].value>heap[max].value)))
    {
        max=l;
    }

    if(max!=i)
    {
    swap(heap[max],heap[i]);
    heapify(max);
    }
}

void heapsort()
{
    for (int i=n/2-1;i>=0;i--) 
        heapify(i); 

    while(n>0)
    {
        swap(heap[n-1],heap[0]);
        --n;
        heapify(0);             
    }
}
int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter the no of elements : ";
    cin>>n;
    Det(n);
    heapsort();
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

> if my input is be (1,3) (2,5) (1,2) my expected output should be (1,2) (1,3) (2,5) but this is not what i'm getting.I'm getting some random numbers as output.

Comment: Can you add a `main` function, which reproduces your problem?

Comment: Watch out for the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: Your variable `n` is initialized but you don't give any value to it, meaning it has a random value. And then you are doing all your loops in `heapsort` over it. That sounds a bit strange to me

Comment: @DrosvarG global variables are `0` initialized by default. That is exactly the problem. `heapsort` does nothing with `n == 0`.

Comment: Is this assignment inside the `if` deliberate? `(heap[r].key = heap[max].key)`

Comment: not answer, but this does not looks like `hashmap` for me in any way.

Comment: I suggest adding `operator<` to the hashmap for easier integration with standard algorithms as well as your own heapsort: `inline bool operator<(const hashmap& rhs) { return std::tie(key, value) < std::tie(rhs.key, rhs.value); }`

Comment: @mch I have added the main function and in the main function the value if n is assigned before the call for heapsort() is called.So is it still a problem to keep the global variable still unassigned

Comment: @mch Yeah that was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to sort on key, then on value, you could alternatively use [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a comparison function :

```
struct hashmap{
   int key;
   int value;
};

bool comp(const hashmap& a, const hashmap& b) {
    return tie(a.key, a.value) < tie(b.key, b.value);
}

int main()
{
  vector<hashmap> v{
       {1, 3}
     , {2, 5}
     , {1, 2}
  };

  sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);

  for (const auto& h : v) {
    cout << '(' << h.key << ',' << h.value << ')';
  }
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you declare all functions as `function` variable with a lambda? `function<bool(const hashmap& a, const hashmap& b)> comp =
  [](const hashmap& a, const hashmap& b)` seems to be more work than `bool comp(const hashmap& a, const hashmap& b)` and is also less readable IMHO.

Comment: @R0m1 But is it fine to use std::sort or is there any chance of error possible which could be prevented by not using std::sort?

Comment: @Bad_Panda Personnally, I'd rather use std::sort rather than any sorting algorithm I could write myself, for the simple reason that writing a good sorting algorithm can be quite tricky. Unless I'm missing something here, I don't see any  reason not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do not need while loop in your heapsort function. Calling it like below will be enough:

```
void heapsort()
{
    for (int i=n/2-1;i>=0;i--) 
        heapify(i); 
}
```